# passing argument 1 of 'fopen' from incompatible pointer type?

Tags: c

I'm stuck for sometime in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *fn; int a;

int exists(const char *fname)
{
    FILE *file;
    if (file = fopen(fname, "r"))
    {
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

main(){

    printf("Name:\n");
    scanf("%s",&fn);

    a=exists(&fn)

    if(a==0){
        fopen(&fn,"w");
        fprintf(fn,"banhdhsjha");
    }
}
```

When I try to run the program, it works until `fprintf(fn,"banhdhsjha");`, but it crashes here [(Windows gives me an error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NELVl.png) and the compiler (CodeBlocks) gives me the following notice:

> passing argument 1 of 'fopen' from incompatible pointer type.

I am trying to make `fprintf` write data in the file, but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: &fn is the address of fn, whose type is "pointer to pointer to char", but fopen() first argument must be "pointer to char". So, you have to pass fn in straight form.

Comment: For reference, `fprintf()`'s man-page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html

Answer (score 5):

There are quite a few problems in your code.

1. You are passing `&fn` to `scanf`. This `&fn` is a pointer to pointer of `const char **` type. This does not make sense. Format specifier `%s` requires a `const char *` argument, not `const char **`. You are basically using the pointer `fn` itself as a target buffer for file name (4 or 8 bytes long, depending on your platform's pointer size). Most likely you type in longer file name than that "buffer" can accommodate. That overrides memory in your program and leads to unpredictable (undefined) behavior.
2. The proper form is probably `scanf("%s", fn)`, but the problem is that you never allocated memory for the target buffer. You have to make sure that `fn` points to a `char` buffer of sufficient size to hold your file name.
3. Your `fopen(&fn,"w")` suffers from the same problem (and that is what the compiler is telling you). `fopen` expects an argument of `const char *` type and you are passing a `const char **` instead. The proper form is `fopen(fn,"w")`, but again, see 2. Also, `fopen` return a file handle that you are supposed to store and use later. You are ignoring (discarding) the return value of `fopen`. That also makes no sense. You need an additional `FILE *` variable to store the return of `fopen`. You already know that, judging by what you did in `exists` function, but somehow you are ignoring that knowledge in your `main`.
4. Your `fprintf` call also makes no sense at all. `fprintf` requires file handle (of `FILE *` type) as its first argument. Instead, you are trying to pass it a file name. That's not going to work and that's also going to trigger a diagnostic message from the compiler. You are supposed to store the return value of `fopen` (as I said in 3) and pass it to `fprintf`.
5. Your `exists(&fn)` call suffers from the same problem as 1 and 3 and produces the same diagnostic message as your `fopen` call.

Stop trying to write random code. Where did you get the idea to pass file name to `fprintf` instead of file handle? Read the documentation for each function you are trying to use and act accordingly.

Comment: The only problem I'm having at the moment is the `fprintf()` which is not working. It should write in the file but it's not doing this. I am aware of the other problems, but at the moment I need to hurry and finish this.

Comment: I am grateful for your answer, please don't erase it (I'll check it in the future and try to learn it decently). But at the moment I'm kinda desperate to do this, this is for an exercise at university and I'm completely lost.

Comment: @Vladimir Putin: The title of your question says that you have problems with `fopen`. Now you claim that it is `fprintf`... Anyway, no, you are having problems with *all* that I mentioned in my answer. Your code will not work unless you fix all of these issues. And see entry #4 for `fprintf`

Comment: OMG! I did it! I did the following: `FILE *b = fopen(&fn,"w"); fprintf(b,"banhdhsjha");` Sorry for the mess, I'm deeply confused for some days. It is now copying it correctly to the file (although I admit I have little clue of what's going on).

Comment: @Vladimir Putin: That is the correct thing to do. But your `&fn` mess is still there and it absolutely has to be fixed.